# PHP Regex - get values between ^

Tags: php, arrays, regex, function

Cannot figure this out.

I have string

`^c1_e^,^d_e^,^c^`

What would be the regex to get the values between`^` and `^`?

I tried

```
preg_match("/(?<=^).*?(?=^)/", $string, $match);
```

which doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier solution:

```
<?php
$string = '^c1_e^,^d_e^,^c^';
preg_match_all('/([^^,]+)/', $string, $matches);
$strings = $matches[1];
print_r($strings); //prints an array with the elements from $string
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the carets. These by default mean 'beginning of line' in regex:

```
preg_match('/(?<=\^).*?(?=\^)/', $string, $match);
```

The above will get the `,` as well, but also only the first match. If you want to avoid the commas and get all the matches, you need to match the `^` and use a capture group:

```
preg_match_all('/\^([^^]+)\^/', $string, $match);
```

The array containing the parts in between the `^` will be in the array `$match[1]`.

A non-regex solution (though a little less robust since it cannot work with a string in a format like `^abc,def^, ^abc^` where it should give out `abc,def` and `abc`) would be to split first, then remove the `^`:

```
$theString = '^c1_e^,^d_e^,^c^';
$elements = explode(',', $theString);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($elements); $i++) {
    $elements[$i] = trim($elements[$i], "^");
}
print_r($elements);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this `~\^(.*?)\^~`

```
<?php
$str="^c1_e^,^d_e^,^c^";
preg_match_all("~\^(.*?)\^~", $str,$match);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($match[1]);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => c1_e
    [1] => d_e
    [2] => c
)
```

[image]